# Cannot install Java SDK into IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea

I use Linux Mint 17 "Qiana" and I've downloaded and installed IntelliJ IDEA to learn Java. Now, while trying to set up JDK for a new project, I get an error `The selected directory is not a valid home for JDK`. The path to JDK I try to use is `/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386`. I also tried to use `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin` but it does not work as well. Is there any way to fix it without some magic or shamanry?

P.S. When I try to set a new Android project (what is the purpose of my Java studies) up, it doesn't see my Android SDK as well.

P.P.S. When I first faced this problem, I installed IDEA as a common user.  So I removed it and re-installed using `root` privileges but that didn't work. :(

Comment: How did you install Java? That seems to be the issue.

Comment: @cricket_007 of course I did, since I have such paths as `java-7-openjdk-i386` or  `java-8-oracle`. The matter is that I used Eclipse before and had no problem while installing and using it

Comment: I think the Oracle java is required for Android development. Can you `echo $JAVA_HOME` from the terminal?

Comment: @cricket_007 http://postimg.org/image/nswj9du2p/ here are my environment paths

Comment: Are you sure you have the JDK installed and not the JRE?

Comment: @cricket_007 yup, 'cause as I've already told, I had Eclipse before, and had no problems during the installation and later

Comment: Not sure what to tell you, then. Sorry

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this yet but I'm pretty sure it should be `/usr/bin/java/` location.

Try `/usr/local/java`.

https://askubuntu.com/questions/130186/what-is-the-rationale-for-the-usr-directory

I understand it is Ubuntu but it's worth a try

Comment: unfortunately, that doesn't help :(